# Animation controller doesn't get initialized . Building a sign in page

Tags: python-3.x, flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:onetarget/screens/background_painter.dart';

class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthScreenState createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller; ----ERRRRROR[enter image description here][1]

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox.expand(
              child: CustomPaint(
            painter: BackgroundPainter(),
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to build a sign in page but it doesn't work. I did everything and copy paste it from the original video: https://youtu.be/bpvpbQF-2Js
[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/bpvpbQF-2Js)

GitHub:[enter link description here](https://github.com/bgrnaymane/OneTarget.git)

Answer (score 0):

Just mark it late.

```
late AnimationController _controller;
```